# How can I prevent a piston from staying extended when a nearby pressure plate is activated?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

To quote the image below:

> The idea behind this circuit is to trap villagers at their work stations during working hours, but let them roam free during normal hours so that they can breed and interact.

I am essentially creating a simple AND gate between a daylight detector and a pressure plate to trigger a piston. I believe the problem I'm having is that when the piston is triggered by redstone, the pressure plate current travels through the piston arm and keeps the piston extended even after removing the redstone source.

*See image for more context*
[image]

Some solutions I have tried are:

1. Place the pressure plate on a slab instead of a full block. This stopped the piston from staying extended, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get a redstone signal from the slab, to travel below the surface. Every solution I found had surface level exposed redstone (not ideal).
2. Place the pressure plate on an observer and do some nonsense with a flip flop circuit. Again, this stopped the piston from staying extended (I guess observers don't conduct redstone signals), but there were some edge cases where the piston would be triggered after a villager left the pressure plate and they'd be locked out of their work station.

I'm open to any ideas you might have. You can try to solve my piston staying extended problem, or if you can think of another solution to my work station problem in general (must be sub-surface and doable in vanilla survival Minecraft), I'd be open to that too.

Comment: Hey, it looks like you may be falling victim to Quasi-Connectivity. You can read about it here: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity

Comment: Have you tried using, or do you have room for, tripwires?

Comment: No room for tripwires. It's a 1x1 confined space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by having a slab under the pressure plate. You can then take the signal from the pressure plate with a sticky piston moving a redstone block:

[image: holding cell mock]

Comment: Awesome solution. I didn't even think of using another piston. Very clever, thanks!